# tagging docker image in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

after build a docker image using `docker.build(<image_name_1>)` I want to tag the docker `image_name_1` to `image_name_2` using jenkinsfile. Is there a way to do it using docker.tag? or I should use sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `docker.tag` global var method for this:

```
// store the resulting build object in the variable "image"
image = docker.build(<image_name_1>)
// re-tag the image
image.tag(image_name_2)
```

and then your image will have both tags locally, and both tags can also be pushed to a registry.

Comment: I am not sure if this works, at least when I try to give the image a new name, I end up with ´image_name_1:image_name_2´ kind of tag (the image name becomes a tag rather than a new image). Is there a way to rename this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use sh command in your jenkinsfile

```
stage ("Tag Image") {
  steps {
    script {
      sh "docker tag docker.build(<image_name_1> docker.build(<image_name_2>"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the shell command for re-naming the images.

```
image = docker.build(<image_name_1>:<tag_1>)
sh("docker tag <image_name_1>:<tag_1> <image_name_2>:<tag_2>")
```

The default tag produced by the build command is "latest" if omitted.